# html5 presentation

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, presentation

I've been looking at http://html5slides.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/template/index.html#1 and was wondering is it possible to modify this code so that there could be more than just one row.

For example, right now it only slides left and right but if I would like to go down by pressing the down arrow? It would take to a seperate row with separate left/right navigation and so on and so on.

I've been trying to do this but the script counts all the `<article>` tags and eventually places them in one row.

Do anyone have an idea on how to atempt it or maybe some other script that could work like in description above? The main idea is to end up with a kind of grid that can be navigated in all directions using arrows.

Answer (score 4):

```
  function nextSlide() {
      if (buildNextItem()) {
         return;
      }

      if (curSlide < slideEls.length - 1) {
         curSlide++;
         updateSlides();
      }
   }

   function prevSlide() {
       if (curSlide > 0) {
           curSlide--;
           updateSlides();
        }
   }

   function updateSlides() {
       for (var i = 0; i < slideEls.length; i++) {
          switch (i) {
            case curSlide - 2:
              updateSlideClass(i, 'far-past');
              break;
            case curSlide - 1:
              updateSlideClass(i, 'past');
              break;
            case curSlide: 
              updateSlideClass(i, 'current');
              break;
            case curSlide + 1:
              updateSlideClass(i, 'next');      
              break;
            case curSlide + 2:
              updateSlideClass(i, 'far-next');      
              break;
            default:
              updateSlideClass(i);
              break;
            }
         } 

         triggerLeaveEvent(curSlide - 1);
         triggerEnterEvent(curSlide);

         window.setTimeout(function() {
         // Hide after the slide
            disableSlideFrames(curSlide - 2);
         }, 301);

         enableSlideFrames(curSlide - 1);
         enableSlideFrames(curSlide + 2);

         if (isChromeVoxActive()) {
             speakAndSyncToNode(slideEls[curSlide]);
         }  

         updateHash();
     }
  }
```

These appear to be the main function driving the slide flip.
No Reason you couldn't expand it to `curSlideX` and `curSlideY`
and have the `updateSlide` move either sideways or vertically depending on which of the two changed.

in the html you have

```
  <section id=slides>
      <atricle></article>
      <atricle></article>
      <atricle></article>
  </section>
```

with the articles being given dynamic classes to determine if the are large, or made small and off to the side.

You would add more rows by more sections, and have the update alter their classes much in the same way that the article classes are moving around to accommodate which article and row is selected.

Comment: Thank you @gbtimmon for answer. Theoretically I can see what you suggest to do here but it turns out that is way above my head and I lack such programming skills.
So if there's anyone who could help me a bit further with modifying this script I would much appreciate it, although I realize that it's quite a naive request ;-)